# SQL trigger error report

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

So I've got the assignment to write a trigger that is supposed to swap data between two columns - LAST_NAME and EMAIL in a record that got a SALARY column updated. And this is what i came up with

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER SWAP
  FOR UPDATE OF SALARY ON MY_EMP
  COMPOUND TRIGGER
  AFTER EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
      UPDATE MY_EMP SET LAST_NAME = EMAIL, EMAIL = LAST_NAME WHERE :OLD.SALARY <> :NEW.SALARY;
    END AFTER EACH ROW;
END SWAP;
```

And when i try to execute this:

```
UPDATE MY_EMP
SET SALARY = SALARY + 100
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 198;
```

I'm getting an error report:

```
UPDATE MY_EMP
SET SALARY = SALARY + 100
WHERE EMPLOYEE_ID = 198
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: table PWR_14_15_L_013209985.MY_EMP is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "PWR_14_15_L_013209985.SWAP", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'PWR_14_15_L_013209985.SWAP'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
       this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
       in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any solutions?

Comment: The error message explains clearly what the problem is. What more do you want us to say?

Answer (score 0):

Make this a before update, and instead of modifying the underlying table, modify the :new values for the table.

This will allow you to update these before the DML commits.